# Is there way to get xpath and css in Edge Browser?

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, microsoft-edge

I have automated test scripts and they are running fine on Chrome.Now extending support for Edge and IE11 . Few test scripts are failing on Edge Browser. Same locators are working fine in chrome but in Edge they are not working. Do we have any way to identify xpath and css like chrome in Edge browser?

I just want to verify that xpath is matching with the same elements in Chrome and edge browser.

Do we have any way to verify xpath and css on Edge browser like we verify on chrome using $x() and $$() in console?

Comment: Relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace please

Comment: On chrome from console using '$x' we can take xpath . Do we have any way to get xpath and CSS on Edge browser?

Comment: _XPath_ obtained through any tools will be a _absolute xpath_ which will be **flaky** and **fragile** when used across multiple browsers. Construct **relative xpath** instead.

Comment: @DebanjanB  I have constucted relative xpath and they are working fine in chrome and firefox.

Comment: @DebanjanB My question is  "Do we have any way to get xpath and CSS on Edge browser?"

Comment: @Downvoters  can you please explain why you downvoted? In chrome we can verify relative xpath using $x() and CSS using $$() in console . My question is Do we have any way to verify same xpath and css is working on Edge browser?

Comment: This question still sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do and where are you stuck?

Comment: @DebanjanB thanks for your suggestion. but i am clear with my question. Do we have any way to verify xpath and css on Edge browser like we verify on chrome using $x() and $$() in console? If you have solution then please help me

Comment: @Andersson I know the meaning of "relative xpath" and have knowledge to write relative xpath. Please read the question carefully then comment

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

**CSS Selectors**

No, Edge has no functionality to copy CSS selectors using dev tools as other browsers do.

Yes, if you write them yourself you can use `$$()` in the console to verify that they work.

**XPath**

No, Edge has no functionality to copy XPath selectors using dev tools as other browsers do.

Yes, you can use `$x()` to test if they work.

Comment: shouldn't we always write our own locators ? Instead of depending upon some third party tool.

Comment: @cruisepandey I agree. Writing your own locators is the best way to get a good, reliable locator but when you are new, it's helpful to be able to use a tool like that to learn. OP stated that he's writing his own locators. I was just confirming that there is no functionality to copy locators but you can verify them.

Comment: @JeffC and cruisepandey I am writing own locators and verifying  using $x() and $$() in the console of chrome browser.

Comment: @JeffC thanks for your reply but unfortunately we are unable to verify locators in Edge console using $$() for CSS and $x() for xpath. please correct me if I am wrong. Currently using Microsoft Edge 41.16299.371.0

Comment: I tested it yesterday and it was working fine in Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 for me.

Comment: FYI : I just checked that '$x()' for xpath and '$$()' for css works fine in 42.17134.1.0 , however they don't work in 41.16299.371.0 .

Answer (score 0):

As per your question to identify *xpath* and *css* within *Edge Browser* the built-in *debugging protocol* i.e. the **DevTools Protocol** will cater to your needs. The **DevTools Protocol** for *Edge Browser* is still a *Work In Progress*.

Having said that you can still use the [**Microsoft Edge Diagnostics Adapter**](https://github.com/Microsoft/edge-diagnostics-adapter) which exposes a common protocol.

---

### Microsoft Edge Diagnostics Adapter

[**Microsoft Edge Diagnostics Adapter**](https://github.com/Microsoft/edge-diagnostics-adapter#microsoft-edge-diagnostics-adapter) is a protocol adapter that enables tools to debug and diagnose Microsoft Edge using the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/). The latest version of Microsoft Edge Diagnostics Adapter works in Windows 10 - 14393 x64.

### [Installation and Usage](https://github.com/Microsoft/edge-diagnostics-adapter#installation-and-usage)

- Install Microsoft Edge Diagnostics Adapter via npm:

  ```
  npm install edge-diagnostics-adapter
  ```
- You can also download it from the [releases page of edge-diagnostics-adapter](https://github.com/Microsoft/edge-diagnostics-adapter/releases)
- After installing it locally you can execute it as follows:

  ```
  node /path/to/edge-diagnostics-adapter/out/src/edgeAdapter.js --port=9222 --servetools
  ```

### [View and Inspect Debuggable Targets](https://github.com/Microsoft/edge-diagnostics-adapter#view-and-inspect-debuggable-targets)

Now you can navigate to `localhost:9222` and see a list of all the debuggable targets.

### [Supported features and API](https://github.com/Microsoft/edge-diagnostics-adapter#supported-features-and-api)

Following is the list of APIs from Chrome Debugger Protocol which are supported:

```
Area        Method
----        ------
CSS         getComputedStyleForNode
CSS         getInlineStylesForNode
CSS         getMatchedStylesForNode
CSS         setPropertyText
CSS         getStyleSheetText
Debugger    canSetScriptSource
Debugger    disable
Debugger    enable
Debugger    evaluateOnCallFrame
Debugger    getScriptSource
Debugger    pause
Debugger    removeBreakpoint
Debugger    resume
Debugger    setBreakpointByUrl
Debugger    stepInto
Debugger    stepOut
Debugger    stepOver
DOM         getAttributes
DOM         getDocument
DOM         getOuterHTML
DOM         hideHighlight
DOM         highlightNode
DOM         pushNodeByPathToFrontend
DOM         pushNodesByBackendIdsToFrontend
DOM         querySelector
DOM         querySelectorAll
DOM         requestChildNodes
DOM         setInspectModeEnabled
Network     enable
Network     clearBrowserCache
Network     setCacheDisabled
Network     requestWillBeSent
Network     responseReceived
Network     getResponseBody
Page        canEmulate
Page        canScreencast
Page        deleteCookie
Page        enable
Page        getAnimationsPlaybackRate
Page        getCookies
Page        getNavigationHistory
Page        getResourceTree
Page        loadEventFired
Page        navigate
Page        reload
Page        setOverlayMessage
Page        setShowViewportSizeOnResize
Page        screencastFrameAck
Page        startRecordingFrames
Page        startScreencast
Page        stopRecordingFrames
Page        stopScreencast
Runtime     callFunctionOn
Runtime     enable
Runtime     evaluate
Runtime     getProperties
```

Alternatively, you can also download the [**`protocol.json`**](https://github.com/Microsoft/edge-diagnostics-adapter/blob/master/src/chromeProtocol/protocol.json)